# getting `distance` of scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

Using JavaScript is it possible to work out the distance, or how far in pixels a window has been scrolled down?

Answer (score 13):

This will work to get the distance of an element from the top of the document: `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

You need to make sure that the element is scrollable.

From Mozilla MDN:

> If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the element is non-scrollable), scrollTop is set to 0

Answer (score 5):

There is a dual check:

```
var dsocleft=document.all? iebody.scrollLeft : pageXOffset
var dsoctop=document.all? iebody.scrollTop : pageYOffset
```

For IE and others

Comment: I have noticed that Firefox and Chrome on Mac -- the jquery "scrollTop()" method does not work -- it always returns '0'.  Also Firefox on Ubuntu also returns 0

Answer (score 4):

Catch all browsers including IE

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
```

From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/detect-user-scroll-amount.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The window object's scrollY property will give you the distance scrolled vertically.

[window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) on mdn

Answer (score -3):

You can get the scroll offset of the document with `document.body.scrollTop`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I just scrolled up and down the page and document.body.scrollTop was always 0...